# Export Firefox bookmarks (and tags) to CSV?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Firefox lets you export to HTML, and while I could write a script that uses regex to parse that into CSV I was curious if there were any existing utilities / Firefox addons that allowed us to directly export to CSV. Also interested if there is any way to import like this.

Comment: how much no of lines you want to exports..??/

Answer (score 1):

I put this (Powershell script) together just for this question. I do not have a way to import though. See my comments in the code for explanation of what is happening. There is really more to a bookmark than the name and URL but these are the most essential pieces of data so that's all I collected for the CSV. Also, you have to export the bookmarks to HTML, what this does is convert that to a CSV file.

```
#set paths
#where your bookmarks.html is
$bkmarkPath = "C:/Users/jhancock/Desktop/test/FFbookmarks/bookmarks.html"
#where you want your CSV file to be. 
$newCSVPath = 'C:/Users/jhancock/Desktop/test/FFbookmarks/bookmarks.csv'

#get the HTML and parse it out.
$bookmarkpage = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$bookmarkpage.IHTMLDocument2_write($(Get-content $bkmarkPath -Raw))

#get the links, and link names and put into variable.
$atags = $bookmarkpage.all.tags("a") | % innerText; 
$links = $bookmarkpage.links | % ie8_href

#clear the file if it exists  
if (Test-Path $newCSVPath) {
  clear-content $newCSVPath
}

#create a new csvfile if it doesn't exist
"""Name"",""URL""`n" | Out-File $newCSVPath -Append

#add number of lines equal to number of links
For ($i=0; $i -lt $links.length; $i++) {
    "`n"""",""""" | Out-File $newCSVPath -Append
    }

#sleep while file is created
start-sleep 2

#import our fresh CSV file
$csv = Import-Csv $newCSVPath -Header Name, URL | Select-object -skip 1

#populate our links and URLs into the CSV
$numItems = $links.Count
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numItems; $i++) {
    $csv[$i].Name = $atags[$i]
    $csv[$i].URL = $links[$i]
}
#Generate the CSV!
$csv | Export-Csv $newCSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Just thought I'd add, that I tested this on exports from Chrome and MS-Edge also and this successfully converted those bookmark exports to CSV as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe such an extension does not exist as of yet, but I wanted to make you aware that you can also export your bookmarks to JSON format, which might make a conversion to CSV easier compared to working with the HTML export (... depending).

Mozilla's official Firefox support page [Restore bookmarks from backup or move them to another computer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them#w_backup-and-restore) mentions how to do this under "Manual backup", though I find navigating there via the browser menu bar easier:
`Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks`, click the star-shaped button and select `Backup...`. This will prompt the Save File dialogue for a JSON file named `bookmarks-YYYY-MM-DD.json` with the current date.

Edit: the closest solution to using a FF add-on is probably a JavaScript bookmarklet. I included code for a first simple version [in a Gist over on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/keikoro/699e2003d5814bc0d5224a9e78676373). You'd run this with the HTML export of your bookmarks open in your browser.